# Read JSON from string and get access to keys

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing, json.net

Can I read JSON from string and iterate if I don't know what kind of key it stores?

Generally, it will be key value pair?

I know that I can use:
dynamic dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

But I don't have an access to keys.

I'm not trying to deserialize into strongly-typed .net objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JObject.Parse` method and iterate through `KeyValuePair` of `JObject`:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> kvp in jObject)
{
    // Your code.
}
```